# angularjs interferes with echoing php variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs

I'm trying to pull a php variable ($purpose) and show it on the option select. The code that I have (see below) only works when I took out the element attribute ng-model="purpose". If I left the ng-model in-placed, the option select showed Purpose, which indicated php echoinng is did not go through. It seems echoing php variable and using angularjs conflicting with one another. Does anyone have this issue? Is there a workaround?

```
<select id="purpose" class="form-control custom-select" name="purpose" value="<?php if(isset($purpose) or !empty($purpose)) {echo $purpose;}?>" ng-model="purpose" autocomplete="on" required/>
  <option <?php if($purpose == "") echo 'selected';?> value="">Purpose</option>
  <option <?php if($purpose == "1030") echo 'selected';?> value="1030">1Exchange</option>
  <option <?php if($purpose == "1040") echo 'selected';?> value="1040">Non-exchange</option>
  <option <?php if($purpose == "1050") echo 'selected';?> value="1050">Financing</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use **value** attribute when using **ng-model.** Just initialize a variable **purpose** & assign PHP variable to it. Like below:

```
<select ng-init="purpose = <?php if(isset($purpose) or !empty($purpose)) {echo $purpose;}?>" id="purpose" class="form-control custom-select" name="purpose" ng-model="purpose" autocomplete="on" required/>
      <option <?php if($purpose == "") echo 'selected';?> ng-value="">Purpose</option>
      <option <?php if($purpose == "1030") echo 'selected';?> ng-value="1030">1Exchange</option>
      <option <?php if($purpose == "1040") echo 'selected';?> ng-value="1040">Non-exchange</option>
      <option <?php if($purpose == "1050") echo 'selected';?> ng-value="1050">Financing</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

While you might be able to get it work using this style, it is recommended to use JSON to populate data from back-end to angular.

```
<?php
$purpose_arr = array(
  "1030" => "1Exchange",
  "1040" => "Non-exchange",
  "1050" => "Financing"
);

echo "<script> var purpose='" + json_encode($purpose_arr) + "'; </script>"
?>

html:
<select id="purpose" class="form-control custom-select" name="purpose" ng-model="purpose" autocomplete="on" required
    ng-options="value as key for (key, value) in purpose" />
    <option value="">Purpose</option>
</select>

controller:
$scope.purpose = purpose;
```